# DotNetNuke ModuleAction server-side processing

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

In DNN it is possible to add a `ModuleAction` menu item. According [this article](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/132063/DotNetNuke-Tips-and-Tricks-20-Module-Action-Menu-Links) on the DNN site it is even possible to do some additional processing on the server-side. After converting the code to C#, the `ActionHandler` is never called.

This is my code:

```
public ModuleActionCollection ModuleActions
{
    get
    {
        ModuleActionCollection Actions = new ModuleActionCollection();
        ModuleAction urlEventAction = new ModuleAction(ModuleContext.GetNextActionID());
        urlEventAction.Title = "Action Event Example";
        urlEventAction.CommandName = "redirect";
        urlEventAction.CommandArgument = "cancel";
        urlEventAction.Url = "http://dotnetnuke.com";
        urlEventAction.UseActionEvent = true;
        urlEventAction.Secure = DotNetNuke.Security.SecurityAccessLevel.Admin;
        Actions.Add(urlEventAction);
        return Actions;
    }
}

private void MyActions_Click(object sender, DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions.ActionEventArgs e)
{
    DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, string.Format(Localization.GetString("ClickMessage", LocalResourceFile), e.Action.CommandName), ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.BlueInfo);

    switch (e.Action.CommandName.ToUpper())
    {
        case "REDIRECT":
            if (e.Action.CommandArgument.ToUpper() != "CANCEL")
            {
                Response.Redirect(e.Action.Url);
            }
            else
            {
                DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, "Canceled the Redirect", ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.YellowWarning);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And in the page init I attach the event handler:

```
AddActionHandler(new ActionEventHandler(MyActions_Click));
```

I also tried attaching in the page load as done by DNN source itself. 
The menu item is shown and the redirect to http://dotnetnuke.com is executed.
But my breakpoint in `MyActions_Click` is never hit.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I'm running in DotNetNuke 7.1 with module reference to DNN 6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution with `IPostBackEventHandler` instead of the DNN way (until someone corrects me):

```
public ModuleActionCollection ModuleActions
{
    get
    {
        ModuleActionCollection Actions = new ModuleActionCollection();
        Actions.Add(ModuleContext.GetNextActionID(),
                    "Bla",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "javascript:" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "ARGUMENT"),
                    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "ARGUMENT"),
                    false,
                    DotNetNuke.Security.SecurityAccessLevel.Edit,
                    true,
                    false);
        return Actions;
    }
}

public void RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
{
    if (eventArgument.ToUpper() == "ARGUMENT")
    {
        ...

        Globals.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, false);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add `IPostBackEventHandler` to your page class name.

Namespace: `using System.Web.UI;`

Answer (score 0):

I honestly dont think this is a DNN issue.  I would clear down your temp cache and try to debug again.

Leigh

Comment: Hey Leigh, cleared my cache, restarted app pool, reset iis, nothing helped. I found anther way around it with `IPostBackEventHandler`, but like to use DNN way, which has more features...